# Trying to implement a delegate and it isn't working

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am trying to implement a delegate

```
class WebBrowserViewController: KINWebBrowserViewController, KINWebBrowserDelegate, NavigationProtocol {
```

However, the methods associated with it:

```
func webBrowser(_ webBrowser: KINWebBrowserViewController!, didFailToLoad URL: URL!, error: Error!) {
    print("DEBUG 5")

}

func webBrowserViewControllerWillDismiss(_ viewController: KINWebBrowserViewController!) {
    print("DEBUG 1")
}

func webBrowser(_ webBrowser: KINWebBrowserViewController!, didStartLoading URL: URL!) {
    print("DEBUG 2")

}

func webBrowser(_ webBrowser: KINWebBrowserViewController!, didFinishLoading URL: URL!) {
    print("DEBUG 3")

}
```

Simply aren't working.

I had someone help me get this far on another question, but I just have no clue why the methods for this delegate aren't being executed.

Can anyone explain what else I might be missing? I have banging my head on this problem the entire day and I just want to figure out how to call a function when the webpage loads.

What am I missing? Is it something in viewDidLoad()?

Do I need to do something like whateverTheWebViewNameIs.delegate = self? Or something like that?

I'm just totally, utterly lost here.

Comment: Did you assign `self` to  `KINWebBrowser.delegate`?

Comment: Yes, I get Module 'KINWebBrowser' has no member named 'delegate'